# Case Statement with sysdate

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

Good day all.  I have an Excel workbook that has an ODBC connection to an oracle database.  I have a query built into the command text to pull down some data.  I am rather new at doing this stuff and I recently learned of the existence of "case" statements, but I have no clue as to what I am doing.

I am looking for the proper state to produce the following result

If Table.Datefield is less or equal to System Date - 14 days then show "New"
If Table.Datefield is greater than System Date - 14 days then show "Waiting Approval".

I have tried

```
    case 
when "Table"."APPROVEDON" > sysdate - 14 then 'New'
when "Table"."APPROVEDON" < sysdate - 14 then 'Waiting Approval'
else 'N/A'
end as "Status"
```

However, I get a missing expression error.

As I said I am very new to this.  I tried some searching, but I am unsure of what to really search for.

Comment: please post the entire query being used

Comment: To repeat @vkp, your `case` looks correct.  The error would seem to be elsewhere in the query.

Comment: Your case expression returns 'N/A' for Table.Datefield is exactly equal to System Date - 14 days. Is that what you want?

Comment: Post the entire query, was doing some wrong assumptions without it !

Comment: How do you run the query? Do you use VB Macro? Post the code.

Comment: I assume "table.approvedon" is not recognized as a date.

Answer (score 0):

As it is the wrong syntax it was throwing an error. Try this.

```
CASE //columnName//
when //tblname.columnname// > //columnname//- 14 then 'New'
when //tblname.columnname// < //columnname// - 14 then 'Waiting Approval'
else 'N/A'
end as "Status"
```

(you have to tell the query statement on which column you want to perform the case operation).
Hope it helps !!

Comment: You're mixing up the syntax for the simple and searched [`case` expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm). The original code is perfectly valid.

Comment: But when I have checked the same i.e.., without column name it is throwing me a error. (I was checking it in a online sql editor.)

Comment: I don't know where you were looking, but the following runs perfectly fine for me in my Oracle database: `with t as (select sysdate - 15 dt from dual union all select sysdate - 13 dt from dual union all select sysdate - 14 dt from dual) select dt, case when "T"."DT" > sysdate - 14 then 'New' when "T"."DT" < sysdate - 14 then 'Waiting Approval' else 'N/A' end col from t;`

Comment: Oh I am sorry for my confusion. It's working without column name too.